# Asp razor get text from div

Tags: asp.net, razor

I want to get the text from a html div id="mydiv" into an asp razor variable myrazorvariable. How can I do it? Thanks in advance :D

```
<div id="mydiv">
Some text to get inside razor variable
</div>

@myrazorvariable = html("mydiv")
```

I want this...

```
@myrazorvariable = "Some text to get inside razor variable"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no query ability in razor to get at the generated dom/html.  If you want to reuse some text/html, create a variable with that text/html in a variable and output it in the razor view.

```
   @{var myrazorvariable = "Some text to get inside razor variable"}

    <div id="mydiv">
       @myrazorvariable
    </div>
```

You could also put that text/html in a partial view and reference that partial as much as you'd like.

```
<div id="mydiv">
    @Html.RenderPartial("mycustomhtml")
</div>

    @Html.RenderPartial("mycustomhtml")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your reasoning behind this. Is the text in the DIV static html? If yes then you can declare the variable in your MVC view 1st:

```
@{
  var myVariable = "Text from the DIV in here";
}
```

and then you can insert that text into the div:

```
<div id="mydiv">
   @myVariable
</div>
```

If the text in the DIV is dynamically populated then you should already have it in your view model.